# Uploaded files are not being written, can't seem to access $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload

The file I'm uploading is either not getting written into the temporary folder or is it not getting processed by PHP properly....

```
Enctype - Check
Name, Method - Check
Form (syntax) - Check
```

(Take it from me that the data is being passed by the form to the PHP)
The PHP code -

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";  
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

PHP -

```
Filesize - Check
Php.ini file - Check
File Permissions - Check.
```

**Output- Invalid File**

And i don't get any error as well.

And one more thing if it helps -

When i `print_r($_FILES)` i get this following output -

```
Array ( [logo] => Array ( [name] => pixel.gif [type] => image/gif [tmp_name] => E:\sAi\Web Design EC\upload\php34.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 4271 ) )
```

But when i just do an echo `echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]`  it gives NO output.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the name of file attribute in your form is `logo` and you are using `file` in php

i.e: you are using as `$_FILES['file']` where as you should use `$_FILES['logo']`.

Or You can change name of file element "logo" to  "file" in your html form.